# Does Creating an Image of an Amazon EC2 Linux instance cause downtime?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Does Creating an Image of an Amazon EC2 Linux instance cause any downtime? Can I image a running server?

Comment: I think this is more of a ServerFault.com question

Comment: You can choose no reboot when image creation invoked.

Comment: @Jasper van den Bosch, you're absolutely right. I posted here in a panic b/c this is home. Sorry all. I'll vote to delete if it doesn't get migrated by a mod. I'm flagging now.

Comment: @qrtt1, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it and upvote, it worked just fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is my opinion that **No Reboot** should prevent the image creation from rebooting. 
If you are the api user, it also provides [argument **--no-reboot** to do it](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Already answered correctly, but I wanted to add a couple of caveats:

1. *--no-reboot, no guarantee*: When you create an image of a AMI with EBS backed root device, you may opt for `--no-reboot`, but AWS warns about this. It does not guarantee integrity of the file system. If it's really busy instance and heavy RW operations going on, you may get a corrupted image.
2. *Instance Store, no reboot*: Creating an instance store backed image never required reboot to me. It's three simple steps -- bundle-image, upload to S3, and register the image without any rebooting in this whole process.